# Patching in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I have a python file say
`python_file_a.py`

```
def load_content():
    dir = "/down/model/"
    model = Model(model_dir=dir)
    return model

model = load_content()

def invoke(req):
    return model.execute(req)
```

test_python_file_a.py

```
@patch("module.python_file_a.load_content")
@patch("module.python_file_a.model", Mock(spec=Model))
def test_invoke():
    from module.python_file_a import model, invoke
    model.execute = Mock(return_value="Some response")
    invoke("some request")
```

This is still trying to load the actual model from the path "/down/model/" in the test. What is the correct way of patching so that the `load_content` function is mocked in the test?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what your code does or how it's used it's hard to say exactly, but in this case the correct approach--and in many cases--is to not hard-code values as local variables in functions.  Change your `load_content()` function to take an argument like:

```py
def load_content(dirname):
   ...
```

or even give it a default value like

```py
def load_content(dirname="/default/path"):
    pass
```

For the test don't use the `model` instance instantiated at module level (arguably you should not be doing this in the first place, but again it depends on what you're trying to do).

**Update:** Upon closer inspect the problem really seems to stem from you instantiating a module-global instance at import time.  Maybe try to avoid doing that and use lazy instantiation instead, like:

```py
model = None
```

then if you really must write a function that accesses the global variable:

```py
def invoke():
    global model
    if model is None:
        model = load_content()
```

Alternatively you can use a [PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/) module-level `__getattr__` function.

Or write a class instead of putting everything at module-level.

```
class ModelInvoker:
    def __init__(self, dirname='/path/to/content'):
        self.dirname = dirname

    @functools.cached_property
    def model(self):
        return load_content(self.dirname)

    def invoke(self, req):
        return model.execute(req)
```

Many other approaches to this depending on your use case.  But finding some form of encapsulation is what you need if you want to be able to easily mock and replace parts of some code, and not execute code unnecessarily at import time.